# How to compare thread's result with other variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, variables, c++11

The thing is I have one function that calculates and gets result of these operations. After getting result I want to compare and get the best result using criteria. The problem is that I do not know if it is good idea to compare variable with result got by threads. Is it going to mess up things for example if two threads are comparing with this variable at the same time or it has some sort of defense?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

double RESULT;

void call_from_thread(int i)
{
    //some calculation
    double result;
    if(result>RESULT)
    {
        RESULT=result;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::thread t[64];
    for(int i=0;i<64;i++)
    {
        t[i]=std::thread(call_from_thread,i);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<64;i++)
    {
        t[i].join();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Is it going to mess RESULT?
Any ideas except defining 64 more variables or this is the only way?

Comment: You probably need some synchronization mechanism to avoid concurrent access to your variable.

Comment: Flagged as "unclear" - please show some code, and/or give an example.

Comment: I added code with example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use asyncs, and do all of comparison in main thread. In this case you won't need for any synchronization. I.e.:

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

double foo(int i) {
    // Do the compuation and return result like this
    return static_cast<double>(i);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double RESULT;
    std::vector<std::future<double>> asyncs;

    for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
        asyncs.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, 
                                    foo, i));

    for(auto & future : asyncs) {
        double result = future.get();
        if(result > RESULT)
            RESULT = result;
    }

    std::cout << RESULT << std::endl;
}
```

In other case, you'll need to create global `std::mutex` and use acquire it with std::lock_quard each time you set result. I.e.:

```
std::mutex mtx;

...

void add_result(double result) {
    std::lock_quard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

   if(result > RESULT)
        RESULT = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code suffers form a **race condition** on the global variable `RESULT`. Different threads are reading and writing this variable. There is no guarantee that this will result in the correct answer, whatever 'correct' may mean, and running the same code several times will most likely give different `RESULT`s.

There are several ways to deal with such race conditions. The best is to avoid them all together, as in myaut's answer. However, sometimes they cannot be avoided. In this case, you must either use `atomic` access or protect the access by a `mutex`. For the case of a `double`, a `mutex` is presumably the best solution and would look like

```
std::mutex MUTEX;
double RESULT;

void call_from_thread(int i)
{
    //some calculation
    double result;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(MUTEX);  // see documentation
    if(result>RESULT)
    {
        RESULT=result;
    }
}
```

It is important that you proteced both the reading (in `result>RESULT`) and writing (in `RESULT=result`) by the same critical region (here defined to be scope of the variable `lock`).